# Install PHP Extensions Without Rebuild

Tags: nginx, vps, php

I've got a VPS setup with Nginx & PHP5-FPM.
Being fairly new to unix, VPS etc... it took me ages to get the setup I wanted.

However Now I want to be able to install some extensions onto PHP without haveing to rebuild the entire thing. For example. Is there a way to install the php_tidy extension on an existing PHP setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile an extensions as a shared library. Then you just have to declare your module in the php.ini.

There is a description at php.net for [phpize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php).

Performance differences between a module and a full compilation are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255055/compiling-php-with-modules-vs-using-shared-modules).

Comment: I haven't got time to try this now, but it looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation at http://pecl.php.net/ on how to install PHP extensions.

It's usually as easy as running a command such as

```
pecl install tidy
```

Comment: okay, but I thought this only works for php4? Will it work for PHP5 as well?

Comment: The above command `pecl install tidy` returned the following error `configure: error: Cannot find libtidy ERROR: /etc/pear/temp/download/tidy-1.2/configure --with-tidy' failed`